# LaserScan message in ROS from a simulated Hokuyo laser

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

real:
1.1239999532699585, 1.1260000467300415, 1.1260000467300415, 1.1260000467300415, 1.128000020980835, 1.128999948501587, 1.128999948501587....
sensor_msgs/LaserScan

simulated:
[-5.592209339141846, -5.592210292816162, 2.2351741790771484e-08]....
std_msgs/String

How can I get a sensor_msgs/LaserScan from the simulated Hokuyo?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149606/laserscan-message-in-ros-from-a-simulated-hokuyo-laser/) by [nita-daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/14501/nita-daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By using the libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser plugin as for example [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/blob/master/rrbot_description/urdf/rrbot.gazebo). See also [this explanation on the gazebo wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#GPU_Laser).

/edit: For Blender, your best bet is either using [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/) which [apparently can generate ROS LaserScan messages](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/stable/_modules/morse/middleware/ros/laserscanner.html) or using [Blensor](http://www.blensor.org/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1